# Firebase Analytics custom list of values

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to use the bundle method `putStringArrayList()` but I'm always getting an error in firebase console.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

ArrayList<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();
types.add("test1");
types.add("test2");
bundle.putStringArrayList("Types", types);

mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("MainActivity", bundle);
```

In Firebase console I get this error:

```
error_value Types
firebase_error 4
```

And a link to [Analytics Error Codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/errors) (Event parameter value is too long).

How I am supposed to send more than one value for a specific key?

Comment: what about parsing the array-list of strings to String.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the API docs for [logEvent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#public-methods), the **params bundle** description says

> **String**, **long** and **double** param types are supported.

You are getting this error because  the **param type** you're using is a map to a **String array list** which is **not supported**. Take a look at [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/17v1TeX1KK8/gGbVR5zoDwAJ) in the firebase google group.

You could instead do something like this, which would essentially be the same.

```
bundle.putString("Types", types.toString());
```

Comment: Be aware that there is a [100 character limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/analytics/parameter.html) to string parameters. For long arrays .toString() is likely to fail.

Answer (score 2):

The [limit on the length of parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param) for Google Analytics for Firebase are as follows:

**Param names can be up to 40 characters long, may only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores ("*"), and must start with an alphabetic character. Param values can be up to 100 characters long. The "firebase*", "google_" and "ga_" prefixes are reserved and should not be used.**

You can make use of the audience in order to filter out the parameter based on the value. For example, you can log an event such as "type" with a parameter "type_name=" and then you can create an audience of users who log type with a particular type_name value.

Comment: I have read these document about the error code . The question here is how to send the list of string values in the custom events.